# Проблема с while

Tags: python, while, syntax

пишу код, привожу его часть, в расчетную часть лучше не вникать) (интересует часть с l)

```
i = 0

j = 0

l = 0

F = 0

while i <= N:

    j = 0

    k = i+1

    l = i-1

    while j <= 2:

        R[i][j] = R[i][1]+V[i][j]*dt+W[i][j]/2*dt*dt

        V[i][j] = V[i][j]+W[i][j]*dt

        F = 0

        while k < N:


            while l >= 0:

                F += 24*ep*sigma**(6)*(1/(dist(i, l, j)^7)-2*sigma^(6)/(dist(i, l, j)^13)

                l -= 1

            F += 24*ep*sigma**(6)*(1/(dist(i, k, j)^7)-2*sigma^(6)/(dist(i, k, j)^13)

            k += 1

        W[i][j] = -F/M[i][0]

    i += 1
```

В общем на фразе l -= 1 выдает invalid syntax, никак не пойму, в чем же проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке

```
F += 24*ep*sigma**(6)*(1/(dist(i, l, j)^7)-2*sigma^(6)/(dist(i, l, j)^13)
```

пропущена скобка

исправленный вариант

```
F += 24*ep*sigma**(6)*(1/(dist(i, l, j)^7))-2*sigma^(6)/(dist(i, l, j)^13)
#                                       ^^^^
```